# How do I suppress the results from a stored procedure from within a stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a stored procedure (we'll call it A) that calls another stored procedure (we'll call this one B). B includes a SELECT that I do not want to send back to the caller of A.

Here is some really rough pseudocode, but it should get the idea across.

```
PROCEDURE A
    CURSOR
        CALL B -- I WANT TO SUPPRESS THE RESULTS FROM B
    END
    SELECT *
END
PROCEDURE B
    Do some interesting things
    SELECT *
END
```

As you can see above, A calls B and B does some things that I want and returns results that I don't care about. Once A is done, it returns its own set of results.

How do I suppress the results from B in A? I'm using SQL Server 2005. I would prefer not to make changes to B because it is working and more complex than I want to mess with.

Comment: add a parameter to procedure B so it knows when to skip the result set, modify procedure A so it utilizes this new parameter as necessary.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
/* Assume this table matches the output of your procedure */
DECLARE @tmpNewValue TABLE (newvalue int)
INSERT INTO @tmpNewValue 
EXEC ProcedureB
```

Comment: That's a great solution. But it still causes overhead, doesn't it? I think there should have been an option like `SET NORESULTSETS ON`. I almost always call an SP just for its side effects and I'm not interested in the output of it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can nest only `insert into exec`. So if you use the same approach in the parent, things will crash.

Comment: NOTE: you have to know the shape of the resultset... and there can't be multiple resultsets

Answer (score 1):

Am I being really really stoopid but shouldn't "Do some interesting things" be in another procedure?
Then Procedure A would call procedure C (which only does "Do some interesting things") and then do its required select and Procedure B could also call procedure C and do its select, rather than having the overhead of a second select and a temporary table that is only used as a dustbin?

Comment: OP "would prefer not to make changes to B"

Comment: It's very common for an SP that does some work to then return a result, such as the id of a newly-created row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a light modification of proc A & B that would suit your needs:

```
PROCEDURE A
    CURSOR
        CREATE TABLE #__suppress_results (col1 int)
        CALL B -- I WANT TO SUPPRESS THE RESULTS FROM B
    END
    SELECT *
END
PROCEDURE B
    Do some interesting things
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#__suppress_results') IS NULL BEGIN
      SELECT *
    END
END
```

This avoids the problem of nested `INSERT...EXEC`, and preserves the existing behavior of proc B. On the off chance that some other calling proc already creates a temp table named `#__suppress_results` before calling proc B, just use a different name, like `#__@supress_results`.

And it works, because `#__suppress_results` is visible within proc B if proc B is called from proc A.

Comment: This is a great option for when your procs are already being used all over the place and so you can't just make changes. This lets you wrap them. Cheeky global variables ftw.

Comment: Ha, this *is* a nice solution. Hats off to the younger me! I miss T-SQL programming.