# How to Suppress the SELECT Output of a Stored Procedure called from another Stored Procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not talking about doing a "SET NOCOUNT OFF".  But I have a stored procedure which I use to insert some data into some tables.  This procedure creates a xml response string, well let me give you an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertSomeData] (@myParam int) AS
DECLARE @reply varchar(2048)

... Do a bunch of inserts/updates...

SET @reply = '<xml><big /><outputs /></xml>'
SELECT @reply
GO
```

So I put together a script which uses this SP a bunch of times, and the xml "output" is getting to be too much (it's crashed my box once already).

Is there a way to suppress or redirect the output generated from this stored procedure?  I don't think that modifying this stored procedure is an option.

thanks.

---

I guess i should clarify.  This SP above is being called by a T-SQL Update script that i wrote, to be run through enterprise studio manager, etc.

And it's not the most elegant SQL i've ever written either (some psuedo-sql):

```
WHILE unprocessedRecordsLeft
  BEGIN
    SELECT top 1 record from updateTable where Processed = 0
    EXEC insertSomeData @param = record_From_UpdateTable
  END
```

So lets say the UpdateTable has some 50k records in it.  That SP gets called 50k times, writing 50k xml strings to the output window.  It didn't bring the sql server to a stop, just my client app (sql server management studio).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571670/how-do-i-suppress-the-results-from-a-stored-procedure-from-within-a-stored-proced

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think I found *a* solution.

So what i can do now in my SQL script is something like this (sql-psuedo code):

```
create table #tmp(xmlReply varchar(2048))
while not_done
  begin
    select top 1 record from updateTable where processed = 0
    insert into #tmp exec insertSomeData @param=record
  end
drop table #tmp
```

Now if there was a even more efficient way to do this.  Does SQL Server have something similar to /dev/null?  A null table or something?

Comment: @Dave: Perhaps you've declared @record and you meant to select into @record? In any case, you should look at OUTER APPLY, since it looks like you want to insert into the #tmp table the resultset returned from executing the insertSomeData SP passing as a parameter the "record" column from the next unprocessed row in updatetable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the APPLY's, but it doesn't look like it's what i want.  This sp is used by other processes, but in my case i don't want the output it gives me.  But dumping the result into a temp table i can avoid it being outputted to the screen.

Comment: @Dave: Maybe your pseudo-code is not accurate, but I don't see how the output of the select will even be used in the insert. If it's the select output that you want to suppress, then maybe that's where the problem is: maybe it's not meant to be returning a result set. Maybe that's simply a bug.

Comment: 'select top 1 record from updateTable...' gets the next record to process.  However in the SP insertSomeData, it performs a select statement which prints out a xml string, that's what i'm wanting to suppress.  I've found by doing a 'insert into #tmp exec SP' that the output that used to be printed to the screen, will be dumped into a table, which i can then drop, because i don't care about that output.

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer

Comment: NOTE: you have to know the shape of the resultset... and there can't be multiple resultsets

Answer (score 56):

The answer you're looking for is found in a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571684/550975) by Josh Burke:

```
-- Assume this table matches the output of your procedure
DECLARE @tmpNewValue TABLE ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @tmpNewValue 
  EXEC [ProcedureB]

-- SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM @tmpNewValue
```

Comment: What would you do if ProcedureB called an EXEC procedure?  I do not think MS SQL can have this insert into for nested execs.

Comment: @zachary-scott I don't see why not? This should allow you to nest as deep as you need to. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried it.  You cannot have nested INSERT INTO EXEC.  if ProcedureB does this, caller of ProcedureB  cannot.

Comment: And you used a different `@tmpNewValue` table name for each level of the nesting?

Comment: This works EVEN FOR PROCS THAT RETURN MULTIPLE RESULT SETS, as long as the tables have the same profile (can be UNION'ed). It'll combine them into one table to suppress or (in my case) return all results. Bacon saved!

Comment: NOTE: you have to know the shape of the resultset... and there can't be multiple resultsets

Comment: Yes, you have to know the shape of the resultset, how else do you create a temp table if you don't? Also, you can have multiple result sets as long as they all have the same shape.

Answer (score 16):

Answering the question, "How do I suppress stored procedure output?" really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. So I want to contribute what I encountered:

I needed to supress the stored procedure (USP) output because I just wanted the row count (@@ROWCOUNT) from the output. What I did, and this may not work for everyone, is since my query was already going to be dynamic sql I added a parameter called @silentExecution to the USP in question. This is a bit parameter which I defaulted to zero (0).

Next if @silentExecution was set to one (1) I would insert the table contents into a temporary table, which is what would supress the output and then execute @@ROWCOUNT with no problem.

USP Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SilentExecutionProc
    @silentExecution bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @strSQL VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @strSQL = '';

    SET @strSQL = 'SELECT TOP 10 * ';

    IF @silentExecution = 1
         SET @strSQL = @strSQL + 'INTO #tmpDevNull ';

    SET @strSQL = @strSQL +     
    'FROM dbo.SomeTable ';

    EXEC(@strSQL);
END
GO
```

Then you can execute the whole thing like so:

```
EXEC dbo.usp_SilentExecutionProc @silentExecution = 1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

The purpose behind doing it like this is if you need the USP to be able to return a result set in other uses or cases, but still utilize it for just the rows.

Just wanted to share my solution.

Comment: This answer (a suppress-output bit parameter) was particularly helpful to me because the "insert-into-temp-table"-based answers required that I know the shape of the output-temp table, which may not be the case.  I also liked that the called sproc could still be called elsewhere in a manner that returns records.

Answer (score 6):

I have recently come across with a similar issue while writing a migration script and since the issue was resolved in a different way, I want to record it.
I have nearly killed my SSMS Client by running a simple while loop for 3000 times and calling a procedure.

```
DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 10
WHILE @counter > 0 
BEGIN 
    -- call a procedure which returns some resultset
    SELECT  @counter-- (simulating the effect of stored proc returning some resultset)
    SET @counter = @counter - 1
END
```

The script result was executed using SSMS and default option on query window is set to show “Results to Grid”[Ctrl+d shortcut].

**Easy Solution:** 
Try setting the results to file to avoid the grid to be built and painted on the SSMS client. [CTRL+SHIFT+F keyboard shortcut to set the query results to file].

This issue is related to : [stackoverflow query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659019/out-of-memory-exception-in-sql-2008)

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. "Results to Text" (Ctrl + T) also worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Man, this is seriously a case of a computer doing what you told it to do instead of what you *wanted* it to do.

If you don't want it to return results, then don't *ask* it to return results. Refactor that stored procedure into two:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertSomeData] (@myParam int) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @reply varchar(2048)

--... Do a bunch of inserts/updates...

EXEC SelectOutput
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SelectOutput AS
BEGIN
SET @reply = '<xml><big /><outputs /></xml>'
SELECT @reply
END
```

Comment: I do agree with you there.  If this was something i was allowed to modify, i would split up the stored proc, or append a parameter to not display output, etc.

Comment: You don't know what op was doing. Maybe the stored proc does something and returns the results which are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

From which client are you calling the stored procedure?  Say it was from C#, and you're calling it like:

```
var com = myConnection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "exec insertSomeData 1";
var read = com.ExecuteReader();
```

This will not yet retrieve the result from the server; you have to call Read() for that:

```
read.Read();
var myBigString = read[0].ToString();
```

So if you don't call Read, the XML won't leave the Sql Server.  You can even call the procedure with ExecuteNonQuery:

```
var com = myConnection.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "exec insertSomeData 1";
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here the client won't even ask for the result of the select.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a SQL CLR stored procedure that execs this. Should be pretty easy.

Comment: SQL CLR is new to me, but i am looking into it now, this might be promising.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SQL Server has an option to suppress output (I don't think it does), but the SQL Query Analyzer has an option (under results tab) to "Discard Results".

Are you running this through isql?

Answer (score 0):

You said your server is crashing.  What is crashing the application that consumes the output of this SQL or SQL Server itself (assuming SQL Server).

If you are using .Net Framework application to call the stored procedure then take a look at SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery.   This just executes stored procedure with no results returned.  If problem is at SQL Server level then you are going to have to do something different (i.e. change the stored procedure).

Answer (score 0):

You can include in the SP a parameter to indicate if you want it to do the select or not, but of course, you need to have access and reprogram the SP.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertSomeData] (@myParam int, @doSelect bit=1) AS
DECLARE @reply varchar(2048)

... Do a bunch of inserts/updates...

SET @reply = '<xml><big /><outputs /></xml>'
if @doSelect = 1
   SELECT @reply
GO
```

Answer (score -5):

ever tried `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as an option?

Comment: Dave isn't talking about the number of results affected.