# Dont want Select variable displaying values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

It might be simple but I been having trouble figuring out.
I have a piece of code(Similar to Below Code) where I am assigning bunch of values to bunch of variables via select, it does the job but when I am running it I am getting result set which is causing my SSMS to crash is there way to avoid this....

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Address VARCHAR(100)

SELECT TOP 1 
@Name = Name
@LastName = LastName
@Address = Address
From Person.Address
Where Name = 'Name'
Order By ID
```

I am using the above code in a loop where I am processing around 3-400K rows and pass this variables to a stored procedure, each top 1 select statement throws a result set causing my SSMS to crash I dont really need the select top 1 values to be displayed, any idea how to get rid of this?....

Any help would be much appreciated.

---As requested below is the code, I have hashed few things but this is what it is and I am running it from Query Analayzer as this is only 1 time process so we dont need SP to be created.

```
    DECLARE @retstat INT 
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @Lang TINYINT
    DECLARE @Address CHAR(10)
    DECLARE @ID INT 
    DECLARE @BranchSeqNo INT

    DECLARE @AddressCode VARCHAR(10)    
    DECLARE @Address1 VARCHAR(50) 

    DECLARE @City VARCHAR(30) 
    DECLARE @State VARCHAR(3)   
    DECLARE @PostalCode VARCHAR(15)     
    DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(30)    

    SET @ID = NULL

    UPDATE  RAWClaimTable Set Processed = 0 where Processed is null

    UPDATE  RAWClaimTable SET  ErrorCode = NULL ,ErrorMessage = NULL ,Processed = 0
    WHERE   ErrorMessage IS NOT NULL AND CLAIMID is null 

WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT   *
           FROM     RAWClaimTable
           WHERE    Processed = 0 ) 
BEGIN 

-----Initialize Default Variables 
    SET @Lang = 0 
    SET @Address = 'Import'
    SET @SaveMode = 0 
    SET @ID = Null


    SELECT TOP 1
            @LossDate = LossDate ,
            @ClaimDate = ClaimDate ,
            @OpenDate = OpenDate ,
            @Receivedate = ReceiVeDate ,
            @Name = Name ,
            @Address = Address ,
            @Address1 = Address1 ,
            @City = City ,
            @State = State ,
            @PostalCode = PostalCode ,
            @Country = Country
    FROM    RAWClaimTable
    WHERE   Processed = 0
    ORDER BY ClaimID 

    BEGIN TRY 

        EXEC @RetStat = Usp_ProcessRawData @Lang, @Address, @SaveMode, @ID OUT,
            @BranchSeqNo, @OriginalBranchSeqNo, @IncidentID,
            @AssignmentTypeCode, @PartnershipID, @AccountID,

    END TRY         

    BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT  @RetStat = @@Error
        if @@Trancount > 0 rollback tran
        IF @RetStat != 0
            BEGIN
                update RAWClaimTable set Errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() where ClaiMKey = @Name
            END 
    END CATCH

    IF @ID IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  RAWClaimTable
            SET     ClaimID = @ID ,
                    Processed = 1
            WHERE   ClaiMKey = @Name
        END      
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  RAWClaimTable
            SET     Processed = 1
            WHERE   ClaiMKey = @Name
        END      

END
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the right place?  Assigning values to variables via SELECT does not return a result set.

Comment: Did you add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` on the top of your sp?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866484/how-to-suppress-the-select-output-of-a-stored-procedure-called-from-another-stor

Comment: @Lamak Agree, Setting NOCOUNT ON would be recommended in general, but assigning values to variables does not return a row count.  Still, it could solve his problem somewhere else in the proc.

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki That's what I'm thinking, and would want to know if op is using it on his/her SPs

Comment: I did use Set No Count On, and as Kevin Suchlicki mentioned Select does not return a value but for some reason when I am passing this variables to the SP it is displaying the values.

Comment: @user2284363 Then I it's better if you post your sp code, and also the way that you are executing it

Comment: Need to see your (simplified) loop

Comment: Added the Script what I am running.

Comment: Are you sure the SP Usp_ProcessRawData is not selecting any data?

Comment: That was my thought, too. I think it's likely that Usp_ProcessRawData is returning a result set in some way (or could also use SET NOCOUNT ON).

Comment: you guys were right the inner sp was returning the result set, as it was a vendor code which was encrypted I couldnt look at it and they just sent us a unerypted copy. Thanks a bunch for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CURSOR to loop thru your rows!

```
SET @Lang = 0 
SET @Address = 'Import'
SET @SaveMode = 0 
SET @ID = Null

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT LossDate, ClaimDate, OpenDate, ReceiVeDate, Name, Address, 
       Address1, City, State, PostalCode, Country
    FROM RAWClaimTable
    WHERE Processed = 0
OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
INTO @LossDate, @ClaimDate, @OpenDate, @Receivedate, @Name, @Address,
     @Address1, @City, @State, @PostalCode, @Country

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY 
     EXEC @RetStat = Usp_ProcessRawData @Lang, @Address, @SaveMode, @ID OUT,
          @BranchSeqNo, @OriginalBranchSeqNo, @IncidentID,
          @AssignmentTypeCode, @PartnershipID, @AccountID,
   END TRY         

   BEGIN CATCH        
     SELECT  @RetStat = @@Error
       if @@Trancount > 0 rollback tran
       IF @RetStat != 0
           BEGIN
             update RAWClaimTable set Errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() 
             where ClaiMKey = @Name
           END 
   END CATCH

   IF @ID IS NOT NULL 
       BEGIN
           UPDATE  RAWClaimTable
           SET     ClaimID = @ID ,
                   Processed = 1
           WHERE   ClaiMKey = @Name
       END      
   ELSE 
       BEGIN
           UPDATE  RAWClaimTable
           SET     Processed = 1
           WHERE   ClaiMKey = @Name
       END      

   FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor
   INTO @LossDate, @ClaimDate, @OpenDate, @Receivedate, @Name, @Address,
        @Address1, @City, @State, @PostalCode, @Country
END
```