# How do I specify which stored procedure result set to use?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# class that calls a stored procedure as follows:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<IDataRow> GetDBSData(Int32 myPeriod, DateTime myWEDate)
{
    string dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    string query = string.Format(
        "exec GatherDBSData '{0}', '{1}'",
        myPeriod.ToString(),
        myWEDate.ToString(dateFormat)
    );
    return FileGenerator.GetDataRows(query, DBSMeta.Columns, dict => new DBSDataRow(dict));
}
```

The challenge I'm running into is that the GatherDBSData sproc calls another sproc and I'm getting two result sets back.  All I want is the last result set.  GatherDBSData contains this call...

```
exec GatherPaperlessPayPayrollData @Period, @CheckDate
```

... as the very first thing it does.  The call immediately above populates a table in the DB that my GatherDBSData sproc needs in order to do its work.

The question I have is - Is there a way to call GatherDBSData and instruct it to return only the second result set?  Or can I call GatherPaperlessPayPayrollData inside GatherDBSData and tell it I don't want to see or use the result set so only one is returned?

Comment: **warning** your should not be using string formatting for building sql. - use a real command!

Comment: What does `FileGenerator.GetDataRows` do? That's what's going to actually execute the query, presumably... and we've no idea what that's doing.

Comment: Why not call `GatherPaperlessPayPayrollData` directly?  And why `GatherDBSData` returns 2 datasets - are there places where both are used? If you cannot change the DB part and you only can call `GatherDBSData` - bring data into an ADO.NET object like DataSet or DataReader - there you can separate datasets and take only the second one

Comment: Yuriy, at the moment, that's my workaround.  I've altered my code to call the first sproc, and then immediately after call the second one, and have removed the call inside the 2nd sproc.  It works, for now, but I'm still curious if there is a way to ignore the first result set.

Comment: Jon, this application is a flat file generator to extend that capability to a tool suite we bought that does not have that capability.  The call to GetDataRows pulls each datarow out of the SqlDataReader and formats it for appending to the flat file.  It's working for now, and that is ultimately what I need.  I wish it was more elegant, but I'm getting beyond the exception by implementing it the way Yuriy suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run across this exact same problem a second time, and the workaround used for the initial posting of this question will not work in the second scenario.

In scenario #2, I have an SSRS report that calls a stored procedure.  That stored procedure calls another stored procedure, and in the end, both result sets were being returned, and the report is trying to use the *first* result set, rather than the second.  I need the second result set only. There *IS* a solution to this.

The solution to this problem is a very creative approach taken by dyslexicanaboko when responding to this question: [How to Suppress the SELECT Output of a Stored Procedure called from another Stored Procedure in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866484/how-to-suppress-the-select-output-of-a-stored-procedure-called-from-another-stor)  While dyslexicanaboko's proposal was not the selected answer in that user's case, it proved very effective in my own.

By adding the optional parameter to the stored procedure being called by my report's sproc, I can suppress the output of the result set that I do not want.  Only the second result set is fed to the report.

The new optional parameter:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GatherPaperlessPayPayrollData] 
(
    @Period int,
    @CheckDate datetime,
    @Employee  VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @silentExecution bit = 0
)
```

Altered the last line of the stored procedure like this:

```
IF @silentExecution = 0
     SELECT * FROM PaperlessPay;
```

Altered the call to the stored procedure like this:

```
if @custEID is not null
    begin
        exec InterfaceDev..GatherPaperlessPayPayrollData @Period, @CheckDate, @custEID, @silentExecution = 1
    end
else 
    begin
        exec InterfaceDev..GatherPaperlessPayPayrollData @Period, @CheckDate, @silentExecution = 1
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instruct your stored procedure to only return one results set, then you can add a new parameter to it that allows you to indicate how many / which result sets to return.

If you just want to skip over the first result set returned, you can use SqlDataReader.NextResult() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx to get to the second result set.