# Suppress stored procedure output when called in another stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

So I have `sproc1` which does some things and returns some rows. The important thing is it does some things. I also have `sproc2` which does some things, calls `sproc1` *(which does it's own things)* and returns it's own rows. The problem is when I call `sproc2` I get **2 result sets**. First comes from `sproc1` and second comes from `sproc2`.

Is it possible to easily suppress the `sproc1` when calling it in `sproc2`?

I have two ways to do this as far as I can tell:

- use a temporary table to catch the output of the `exec sproc`.
- in `C#` navigate to the last result set and use that while ignoring the first one(s).

None of these methods is easily reusable as the:

- **first** requires me to `CREATE` a temporary table that matches the output of the stored procedure
- **second** needs me to iterate through the result sets to get to the last one not knowing which is the last one unless I try to move to the next and fail via `.NextResult()`.

The easy way would be if SQL Server allowed me to exec a stored procedure within another stored procedure, but suppress the output of the inner executed it. Or if `SqlCommand` allowed an `ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.LastResult)` and would navigate to the last result by itself.

Can any of the two be achieved in an easy and reusable manner?

The real solution would be to refactor inner stored procedures into `write` and `read` components. Or add a `@param` to inner stored procedures that prevents the final results from being selected. But I'm trying to be lazy here!

Comment: Add a parameter to a second sp and use it within sp2 with "if": if not @suppress_results select....

Comment: You can use sepupic option or another option you find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866484/how-to-suppress-the-select-output-of-a-stored-procedure-called-from-another-stor

Comment: You already went through all options available, need to pick the least troublesome now!

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @MitchWheat I know the problem, I have solutions, but I was wondering if there's some arcane SQLServer knowledge I probably don't have to handle this easier than how I already know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So *(for now, unless I find a better answer or something gets improved)* I ended up adding this argument with a default value so I don't have to think about it at all in the C# side:

```
,@_Suppress bit = 0 -- prevent output via select
```

and right before the `select` I add:

```
if @_Suppress is null or @_Suppress = 0
select -- output results
```

This method also requires you to refactor `insert ... output` code and output into a temporary table and eventually only select if not suppressed.

This is the easiest method to handle things but there should be internal functionality for these cases like:

```
begin suppress
exec some_sproc;
end suppress;
```

or some special syntax like `sexec` *(as in suppressed exec)* or a general use NULL table that can accept any insert columns format and just discard it.

*I'll probably add this argument from now on to all my `sprocs` that produce results and refactor the old ones impacted by this issue.*