# How do I suppress results from multiple stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, suppress

I have a stored procedure sp_1 that calls another stored procedure sp_1_1.

I know how to suppress the results from sp_1_1 using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/571670/67249).

The real problem is that sp_1_1 itself also call another stored procedure sp_1_1_1 which ALSO returns it's results to sp_1_1!!

I may not change either sp_1_1 or sp_1_1_1, and can only change sp_1.

The results returned to sp_1 are 2 recordsets, with the first from sp_1_1 and the second from sp_1_1_1.

**SUMMARY:**

sp_1  (Needs to suppress two recordsets returned from below)

+---- sp_1_1 (returns its own results, then results from below)

+----------sp_1_1_1  (returns results)

Comment: ... This really sounds like an opportunity for some refactoring (ie, split both `sp_1_1` and `sp_1_1_1` into two procedures).  Suppressing your results is really only a short-term gain.  I didn't know that it was possible to return two different results sets from a SP (though, I've never messed much with them) - can you not create two temp tables, like your example?

Comment: As good as your suggestion sounds, refactoring  sp_1_1 and sp_1_1_1 (obviously not the real sp names, just aliases for clarity) is not at all an option as they are used by other processes that use the feedback. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: SQL Server "Denali" gives you new options for handling resultsets.  In this case, because you're nesting you obviously can't use the insert/exec trick.  One kludgy workaround, if you don't want to refactor too much, is to add a parameter to the proc with a default, something like @SuppressResults bit = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, an aside, SQL Server "Denali" gives you new options for handling resultsets.

In this case, because you're nesting you obviously can't use the insert/exec trick.

One kludgy workaround, if you don't want to refactor too much, is to add a parameter to the proc with a default, something like @SuppressResults bit = false.

Then, in the routines that need to be nested, call it explicitly with @SuppressResult=True, and then alter the code in the routines to not select results if @SuppressResults=True.

The important thing is to provide a default and put the parameter at the end. That will prevent existing calls to the routine from elsewhere in the code base needing to be altered.