# How to prevent stored procedures from returning structures from other stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Let say I have 2 Stored Procedures:

```
CREATE spTest1
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Field1 FROM TableA
END

CREATE spTest2
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC spTest1
  SELECT Field2 from TableB
END
```

If we look at the results from `spTest` execution, we can see that 2 result sets are returned.  Is there a way to only return the result set from `spTest2` which is `Field2` from `TableB`?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: This may sound flippant, but the way to stop spTest2 returning 2 result sets is not to return 2 result sets. What's the real problem here?

Comment: I am not returning any result sets, but SQL returns them by default.

Comment: I think, maybe the better answer is that I cannot change spTest1, and I need to return a result set in spTest2.  This answer might be a bit more relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571670/how-do-i-suppress-the-results-from-a-stored-procedure-from-within-a-stored-proce/571684#571684

Comment: Yes. You're effectively running two statements (exec spTest1, and select Field2 from TableB) each of which returns a resultset. SQL properly returns them both. The simple solution is not to call spTest1. But that's an obvious answer which I why I ask what's the real problem here?

Comment: I basically need to suppress the resultset from spTest1 when calling spTest2.  I think the link shared by ASh is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is poor design. If a purpose of a stored procedure is to "return a resultset" like that, it shouldn't be called inside other stored procedures. My guess is the inner procedure does stuff that is necessary for the outer one. The "do stuff" part should be separated from the "return a resultset" part so you don't have to do crazy workarounds.

Comment: I don't disagree with you whatsoever.  The problem arises when a store procedure that is used heavily exist, and then you decide why should I keep a second copy of the procedure and have to maintain it.  Best of 2 evils I guess.

Comment: The problem arises when you don't apply the separation principle. In this case you must separate 3 SP: 1) Do stuff; 2) call #1 and select A 3) call #1 and select B

Comment: I wouldn't keep two copies of the procedure. But theoretically you should be able to split it into two and have the "return a resultset" ALSO call the "do stuff" portion. No need to maintain the stuff in 2 places. (Theoretically at least)

Comment: That actually makes total sense.  I will split the first procedure into 2.